# Literate way of moving all files to a new subdirectory

Tags: linux, console, mv

```
$ mkdir backup && mv * backup/
mv: cannot move `backup' to a subdirectory of itself, `backup/backup'
```

Works, but issues a warning. Also exit code is 1.

How to do it properly (but not [much] longer)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

bash:

```
shopt -s extglob
mkdir backup && mv !(backup) backup
```

Answer (score 2):

Also bash, and sh (afaik):

```
$ mkdir .backup && mv * .backup/ && mv .backup backup
```